CMS : Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed
After upgrade to .NET Core 8 and upgrade from EPiServer CMS 11.20.16  to CMS 12.30.0, we ran into a problem, that for some reason, time to time, getting connection exceptions on using
IContentLoader GetChildren (IEnumerable<T> GetChildren<T>(ContentReference contentLink)) 

and
GetBySegment (IContent GetBySegment(ContentReference parentLink, string urlSegment, CultureInfo language))


ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open.
Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.
ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

Exceptions:

System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open.
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.GetOpenTdsConnection(String method)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ValidateConnectionForExecute(String method, SqlCommand command)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(Boolean isAsync, String method)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at EPiServer.DataAccess.Internal.ContentListDB.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<ListMatchingSegments>b__0() at EPiServer.Data.Providers.Internal.SqlDatabaseExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass26_01.b__0()
at EPiServer.Data.Providers.SqlTransientErrorsRetryPolicy.Execute[TResult](Func1 method) at EPiServer.Data.Providers.Internal.SqlDatabaseExecutor.Execute[TResult](Func1 action)
at EPiServer.DataAccess.Internal.ContentListDB.ListMatchingSegments(ContentReference parentLink, String urlSegment)
at EPiServer.Core.Internal.DefaultContentProviderDatabase.ListMatchingSegments(ContentReference parentLink, String urlSegment)
at EPiServer.Core.Internal.DefaultContentProvider.ListMatchingSegments(ContentReference parentLink, String urlSegment)
at EPiServer.Core.ContentProvider.<>c__DisplayClass79_0.b__0()
at EPiServer.Framework.Cache.ObjectInstanceCacheExtensions.ReadThroughWithWait[T](IObjectInstanceCache cache, String cacheKey, Func1 readValue, Func2 evictionPolicy)


Failed to Read cacheKey = 'EPPageData:2870:en'
System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()
at EPiServer.DataAccess.Internal.ContentLoadDB.LoadContentInternal(ContentReference contentLink, Int32 languageBranchId, DbDataReader reader)
at EPiServer.DataAccess.Internal.ContentLoadDB.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0()
at EPiServer.Data.Providers.Internal.SqlDatabaseExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass26_01.<Execute>b__0() at EPiServer.Data.Providers.SqlTransientErrorsRetryPolicy.Execute[TResult](Func1 method)
at EPiServer.Data.Providers.Internal.SqlDatabaseExecutor.Execute[TResult](Func1 action) at EPiServer.DataAccess.Internal.ContentLoadDB.Load(ContentReference contentLink, Int32 languageBranchID) at EPiServer.Core.Internal.DefaultContentProviderDatabase.Load(ContentReference contentLink, Int32 languageBranchID) at EPiServer.Core.Internal.DefaultContentProvider.LoadContent(ContentReference contentLink, ILanguageSelector languageSelector) at EPiServer.Core.ContentProvider.<>c__DisplayClass123_0.<LoadContentFromCacheOrRepository>b__0() at EPiServer.Framework.Cache.ObjectInstanceCacheExtensions.ReadThroughWithWait[T](IObjectInstanceCache cache, String cacheKey, Func1 readValue, Func`2 evictionPolicy)


System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(Boolean isAsync, String method)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at EPiServer.DataAccess.Internal.ContentLoadDB.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Load>b__0() at EPiServer.Data.Providers.Internal.SqlDatabaseExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass26_01.b__0()
at EPiServer.Data.Providers.SqlTransientErrorsRetryPolicy.Execute[TResult](Func1 method) at EPiServer.Data.Providers.Internal.SqlDatabaseExecutor.Execute[TResult](Func1 action)
at EPiServer.DataAccess.Internal.ContentLoadDB.Load(ContentReference contentLink, Int32 languageBranchID)
at EPiServer.Core.Internal.DefaultContentProviderDatabase.Load(ContentReference contentLink, Int32 languageBranchID)
at EPiServer.Core.Internal.DefaultContentProvider.LoadContent(ContentReference contentLink, ILanguageSelector languageSelector)
at EPiServer.Core.ContentProvider.<>c__DisplayClass123_0.b__0()
at EPiServer.Framework.Cache.ObjectInstanceCacheExtensions.ReadThroughWithWait[T](IObjectInstanceCache cache, String cacheKey, Func1 readValue, Func2 evictionPolicy)


System.InvalidOperationException:
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.GetOpenTdsConnection (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ValidateConnectionForExecute (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5)
at EPiServer.DataAccess.Internal.ContentListDB+<>c__DisplayClass11_0.b__0 (EPiServer, Version=12.21.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7)
at EPiServer.Data.Providers.Internal.SqlDatabaseExecutor+<>c__DisplayClass26_0`1.b__0 (EPiServer.Data, Version=12.21.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7)
at EPiServer.Data.Providers.SqlTransientErrorsRetryPolicy.Execute (EPiServer.Data, Version=12.21.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7)
at EPiServer.Data.Providers.Internal.SqlDatabaseExecutor.Execute (EPiServer.Data, Version=12.21.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7)
at EPiServer.DataAccess.Internal.ContentListDB.ListMatchingSegments (EPiServer, Version=12.21.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7)
at EPiServer.Core.Internal.DefaultContentProviderDatabase.ListMatchingSegments (EPiServer, Version=12.21.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7)
at EPiServer.Core.Internal.DefaultContentProvider.ListMatchingSegments (EPiServer, Version=12.21.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7)
at EPiServer.Core.ContentProvider+<>c__DisplayClass79_0.b__0 (EPiServer, Version=12.21.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7)
at EPiServer.Framework.Cache.ObjectInstanceCacheExtensions.ReadThroughWithWait (EPiServer.Framework, Version=12.21.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7)

As a workaround have added catching InvalidOperationException and retry if it fails, as then app does not crash (success on retry), but it still can throw exception even on retry and now getting also NullReferenceException (related to connection) for GetChildren:

System.NullReferenceException:
at EPiServer.Data.Providers.Internal.ConnectionContext.CloseConnection (EPiServer.Data, Version=12.21.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7)
at EPiServer.Data.Providers.Internal.ConnectionScope.Complete (EPiServer.Data, Version=12.21.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7)
at EPiServer.Data.Providers.Internal.SqlDatabaseExecutor+<>c__DisplayClass26_0`1.b__0 (EPiServer.Data, Version=12.21.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7)
at EPiServer.Data.Providers.SqlTransientErrorsRetryPolicy.Execute (EPiServer.Data, Version=12.21.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7)
at EPiServer.DataAccess.Internal.ContentListDB.LoadSpecificContentInstances (EPiServer, Version=12.21.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7)
at EPiServer.Core.Internal.DefaultContentProvider.BatchLoad (EPiServer, Version=12.21.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7)
at EPiServer.Core.Internal.DefaultContentProvider.LoadContents (EPiServer, Version=12.21.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7)
at EPiServer.Core.ContentProvider.GetContentBatch (EPiServer, Version=12.21.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7)
at EPiServer.Core.ContentProvider.GetScatteredContents (EPiServer, Version=12.21.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7)
at EPiServer.Core.Internal.ProviderPipelineImplementation.GetItems (EPiServer, Version=12.21.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7)
at EPiServer.Core.Internal.DefaultContentLoader.GetChildren (EPiServer, Version=12.21.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7)
at EPiServer.Core.Internal.DefaultContentLoader.GetChildren (EPiServer, Version=12.21.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7)


The error seems to be related to connection with the database, you could try these suggestion to resolve the issue: 1)Enable Pooling=True; and set  Max Pool Size=200;2)Try to increase connection time out if the query is taking longer time 3)Enable logging to get the more detail about where the errors occurs 4)You could try to use the code with  async and await to access the data which can help you with the managing connection properly. if possible, you could share the sample code
